# ¿Como representar en un diagrama ER un atributo que es clave primaria y compuesta al mismo tiempo?

Tags: sql

Estoy creando un diagrama ER, y tengo una estructura como la siguiente:
[image: Modelo ER]

**Y me piden pasar el diagrama al siguiente formato:**

[image: Diagrama ER 2]
Los atributos de la tabla tutor son estudiante_id y profesor_id que hacen referencia a sus respectivas tablas.

Mi duda aquí es, ¿cómo puedo representar el atributo estudiante_id que es clave primaria y foránea al mismo tiempo?, y ¿cómo representar el atributo profesor_id que es clave foránea únicamente en la segunda forma del diagrama ER?

Comment: Buenas, Emiliano, bienvenido al sitio. La verdad es que no aprecio diferencia entre los dos diagramas, aparte de cómo se representan los atributos. ¿A qué te refieres con que profesor_id es clave foránea solo en el segundo? En el primero aparece como FK en la tabla tutor.

Comment: Por cierto, tu diagrama es difícil de ver en el modo oscuro.

Comment: No está relacionado con tu problema, pero te sugiero que no utilices solamente ID como nombres de tus columnas. Siempre especifica de quien es el ID. Lo mismo con el nombre. Así podría quedar `id_estudiante` y `nombre_estudiante` para la tabla de estudiantes.